# Wordpress custom theme seems to load bootstrap css and JavaScript but not formatting content

Tags: wordpress, twitter-bootstrap, themes, bootstrap-5

I am building a custom Wordpress block template theme.  I have added the enqueue script to load query, bootstrap is and bootstrap css.  It is loading it when viewing source; however, when putting in bootstrap content and css classes, Wordpress seems to be ignoring the design and formatting according to Wordpress css.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Site: VoicesOfTheChurch.com

```
Enqueue Script:

    function theme_assets() {
        // Register theme stylesheet.
        $theme_version = wp_get_theme()->get( 'Version' );

     //CSS
        wp_enqueue_style('custombootstrap', 'https:/cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css', array(), '3.4.4', 'all');
        wp_enqueue_style('customstyle', get_template_directory_uri() . '/style.css', array(), '1.0.0', 'all');

        //JS
        wp_enqueue_script('customjquery', 'https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.7.0.js', array(), '2.1.4', true);
        wp_enqueue_script('custombootstrap', 'http://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.2/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js', array(), '3.4.4', true);
        
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'theme_assets' );
```

I added custom HTML and used a bootstrap code I found on the internet to test the formatting on the page where the “shoe” is, here is the code:  As you can see, it isn’t formatting it at all.  The 4 column section is supposed to be formatted with bootstrap as well where it scales down to 4 columns, to 2 columns, to single column on mobile phone.  That is also defaulting to the normal Wordpress column format.

`<div class="container-fluid px-0">   <header>    <div class="shape"></div>   <!-- Navbar --> <nav class="navbar fixed-top navbar-expand-lg navbar-transparent"> <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">SPORT SHOES</a> <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation"> <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span> </button> <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent"> <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto"> <li class="nav-item active"> <a class="nav-link" href="#">HOME <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a> </li> <li class="nav-item"> <a class="nav-link" href="#">MEN</a> </li> <li class="nav-item"> <a class="nav-link" href="#">WOMEN</a> </li> <li class="nav-item"> <a class="nav-link" href="#">KIDS</a> </li> <li class="nav-item"> <a class="nav-link" href="#">BOYS</a> </li> <li class="nav-item"> <a class="nav-link" href="#">GIRLS</a> </li> </ul> </div>   </nav>  <!-- ./ end of navbar -->   <div class="container"> <div class="row">   <div class="col-md-6 left-side">    <img src="https://i.imgur.com/jrRBTai.png" class="w-100">   </div>  <div class="col-md-6 right-side">   <h1>SPORTS SHOES</h1>   <p>FREE DELIVERY</p>    <div class="text-center">   <button class="btn order-button">ORDER NOW</button> </div>  </div>  </div>  </div>  </header>   </div>`

Anything else you need, please let me know.  Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see some typos in your CDN links, try out this code:

Bootstrap Style:

`wp_enqueue_style('custombootstrap', 'https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css', array(), '5.3.1', 'all');`

Bootstrap Script:

`wp_enqueue_script('custombootstrap', 'https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.1/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js', array(), '5.3.1', true);`

Comment: That loaded the bootstrap!!  Thanks!   But for some reason the 4 columns isn’t scaling down.  It’s supposed to be on smallest devices its single, then as you scale it up it goes to 2 side by side, and then finally 4 side by side.  Do you see anything in the code for why it’s not working?

Comment: It seems to only be using the standard Wordpress scaling when it goes from 4 side by side to single.

Comment: I’m using a `container` div, a `row` div, and then each column has `col-12 col-sm-6 col-xl-3` classes

Comment: when I visit your site, it is breaking in 2 spots, 4 cols and then 1 col, I would need to see the code and how it's set up. I suggest marking this question answered, and asking another with the specified code and issue

Comment: it also has some wordpress column classes on it that may be interfering, those classes are on the children, they should be on the parent

Comment: When I took the Wordpress classes off, it messed up Wordpress being able to edit.  I will try that again.  What do you mean this on the children?  What parent should it be on?  The container is on the group, the row is on the columns, and then each column under columns has the col- classes

Comment: apologies, typical bootstrap grid flow:

`<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-12 col-sm-6 col-xl-3">
            <!-- Your content here -->
        </div>
        <div class="col-12 col-sm-6 col-xl-3">
            <!-- Your content here -->
        </div>
        <!-- Additional columns as needed -->
    </div>
</div>`

sorry it's not formatted well in a comment

Comment: That is how I have it designed.  I added another 4 column section to website and took out the wordpress classes.  Still not scaling down.  Are you able to look at it at voicesofthechurch.com ???  Sorry just trying to get additional insight as I'm missing something